# Can't POST on django admin - Can't concat bytes to string

Tags: python, django, apache, http, post

I'm using Django 2.0.9 and Python 3.4.2 on an apache 1and1 shared hosting.

When I make any POST HTTP request to my Djando app, I get the following message:

> Traceback:
>
> File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>   35. response = get_response(request)
>
> File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in
>   _get_response
>   119. response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
>
> File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in
>   process_view
>   289. request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
>
> File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py" in
>   _get_post
>   115. self._load_post_and_files()
>
> File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in
>   _load_post_and_files
>   302. self._post, self._files = QueryDict(self.body, encoding=self._encoding), MultiValueDict()
>
> File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in body
>   263. self._body = self.read()
>
> File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in read
>   322. return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py" in
>   read
>   36. result = self.buffer + self._read_limited()
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /adminlogin/ Exception Value: can't
>   concat bytes to str

I posted the trace of admin login page, but it's the same problem with any POST request.

Here is my settings.py:

```
#Cookie Domain
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN='mydomain.es'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ['mydomain.es', 'www.mydomain.es', 'localhost']

BASE_URL='mydomain.es'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=['mydomain.es']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'mydomain.es', 'www.mydomain.es']

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True

Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'import_export',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_inlinecss',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
'DIRS': ['...myprojectdir/myapp/templates'],
'APP_DIRS': True,
'OPTIONS': {
'context_processors': [
'django.template.context_processors.debug',
'django.template.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
],
},
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'
```

My .htaccess:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Set up static content redirect:
RewriteRule ^(static/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(adminmedia/.*)$ - [L]
# The following two lines are for FastCGI:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(application.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My application.fcgi:

```
#!...myenv/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import traceback
from flup.server import *
home = '...'
try:
    os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'] = os.path.join(home, '...myenv/bin/python')
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'] + ':' + os.environ['PATH']

    project = os.path.join(home, 'myapp')
    # Add a custom Python path.
    sys.path.insert(0, project)

    # Switch to the directory of your project.
    os.chdir(project)

    # Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "myapp.settings"

    from django_fastcgi.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import get_internal_wsgi_application

    wsgi_application = get_internal_wsgi_application()
    runfastcgi(wsgi_application, method="prefork", daemonize="false", minspare=1, maxspare=1, maxchildren=1)
except:
    with open(os.path.join(home, 'tmp/error.log'), 'w') as fp:
        traceback.print_exc(file = fp)
```

Comment: Can you show your Apache configuration?

Comment: Sure, I have edited my last post with my .htaccess and application.fcgi. I don't have super user access, so I can't modify apache/httpd.conf files.

Answer (score 1):

Flup is not compatible with Python3. It looks like there is a fork, [flup-py3](https://pypi.org/project/flup-py3/), which you should install instead.

Really though you should consider a modern hosting environment which allows you to use WSGI.

Comment: I can't move the hosting environment. I have installed pip and I can install  flup-py3, so, could you tell me how i have to modify my application.fcgi??

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything, once you have installed that (and probably uninstalled the original version).